# The identity check failed for the outgoing message. The expected identity is

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-security, x509certificate

Had a wcf service running fine on my machine.

Moved it to a server and am now getting the above error.

I produced a test certificate on the server.

Heres my client config.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>
    </runtime>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsDualHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WSDualHttpBinding_IMessageHandlerServer" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" clientBaseAddress="http://192.168.1.74:8081">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" />
                    <security mode="Message">
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                            algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </wsDualHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://192.168.1.100:8080/" binding="wsDualHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="WSDualHttpBinding_IMessageHandlerServer"
                contract="MessageService.IMessageHandlerServer" name="WSDualHttpBinding_IMessageHandlerServer" behaviorConfiguration="myClientBehavior">
                <identity>
                    <certificate encodedValue="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" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
      <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
          <behavior name="myClientBehavior">
            <clientCredentials>
              <serviceCertificate>
                <authentication certificateValidationMode="Custom" customCertificateValidatorType="MyX509Validator,MessageHandlerClient" />
              </serviceCertificate>
            </clientCredentials>
          </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

EDIT

Proxy initialisation is as follows but this is not where the error is being thrown...

```
InstanceContext context = new InstanceContext(new MyCallback());
            Configuration stockConfiguration = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(new ExeConfigurationFileMap { ExeConfigFilename = @"C:\Users\Ash\Desktop\Config\app.config" }, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

            ConfigurationDuplexChannelFactory<MessageHandlerClient.MessageService.IMessageHandlerServerChannel> stockChannelFactory = new ConfigurationDuplexChannelFactory<MessageHandlerClient.MessageService.IMessageHandlerServerChannel>(context, "WSDualHttpBinding_IMessageHandlerServer", null, stockConfiguration);
            stockChannelFactory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "test";
            stockChannelFactory.Credentials.UserName.Password = "test";
            stockClient = stockChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
```

The error is being thrown when i make a call using the proxy eg

```
stockClient.messageToServerWithoutDirectReturn(moduleName, moduleType, methodName, inputs);
```

Please let me know if you need anymore information.

Kind Regards

Ash

Comment: I'm assuming this happens when you initialize your client proxy. Could you please show the code where you create the proxy to your webservice?

Comment: No the proxy initialisation works fine....
The problem is where I actually call a method through the proxy...
I've included info in main post

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you moved the client to another server and are using a new certificate you will need to update your identity/certificate node:

```
        <identity>
            <certificate encodedValue="..." />
        </identity>
```

It is probably still pointing to your client's identity store and certificate

Comment: thanks for this... how would I go about changing it?
ie how do I know what to set the encoded value to?

Comment: @user589195: How did you generate your config initially? Did you run svcutil? If so, just try to run it again on the server and replace the appropriate parts in your client config.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Refreshed the service reference and used the newly generated encoded value in my external config.

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways to change it.

```
<identity>
    <certificate encodedValue="the value of base64 encoded value of the certificate that you are using">
</identity>
```

or

```
<identity>
    <certificateReference findValue="thumbprint" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My">
</identity>
```